# Atualizando valores em uma ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Eu adiciono os valores que estão dentro de 3 `arrays` no `hashMap` para inserir na `listview`:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lista = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0; i<tema.length; i++ ) {
        HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
        item.put("tema", tema[i]+": "+tempo[i]);
        item.put("palavras", palavras[i]);
        lista.add(item);
    }
```

O que eu quero fazer é que quando o usuário clicar no botão `SUBIR`, por exemplo. O item que ta na posição 2 (se for o que ele tiver clicado) suba para a posição 1, e o que estava na posição 1 ocupe a posição 2.

Substituindo:

```
 up.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(posicao!=0 && tema.length>1) {

              auxtema = tema[posicao-1];
              auxpalavras = palavras[posicao-1];
              auxtempo = tempo[posicao-1];

              tema[posicao-1] = tema[posicao];
              palavras[posicao-1] = palavras[posicao];
              tempo[posicao-1] = tempo[posicao];

              tema[posicao] = auxtema;
              palavras[posicao] = auxpalavras;
              tempo[posicao] = auxtempo;


        }
```

Dentro do array eu consegui fazer. Eu substitui, mas como faço para atualizar isso dentro da *listView*, e atualiza-la?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o seu código não está mostrando como você instanciou a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) não dá para ter certeza se você está utilizando um `adapter` padrão ou seu próprio `adapter`. 
Assumindo que você implementou seu próprio [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) (herdando direta ou indiretamente de [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)) ou usou algum `adapter` capaz de lidar com atualizações dinâmicas (e.g., [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)), a solução é chamar o método [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) após ter atualizado o modelo:

Para fazer isso (assumindo que `listView` é sua `ListView`)

```
((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

**Atualização**: Pela estrutura do seu código você deve estar utilizando um [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html).

Se minha resposta e a do @R3oLoN não fizeram sentido eu recomendo fortemente dar uma lida no tutorial do *Lars Vogel*: [Using lists in Android](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) (em inglês).

Comment: Eu não tenho dados suficientes sobre seu código / adapter para te dar uma solução específica, mas [remover](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) o item da `ArrayList` e chamar `notifyDataSetChanged` deveria funcionar. De uma olhada [nessa resposta do SOE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497580/how-to-dynamically-remove-items-from-listview-on-a-button-click).

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi bem sua duvida, mas caso seu `listview` tenha um `Adapter` você pode implementar uma método que atualiza o `ArrayList` dentro do `Adapter` e chama o método `notifyDataSetChanged`

Ex.:

```
public void atualizarLista(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```